# Marklogic data hub harmonization Job status is cancelled when collector is returning more than 5000 uri

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I am calling flowrunner.run method to do harmonization and we have implemented in such a way if content is harmonized successfully , we will delete a content from stage database based on status value which we will get from job database, but whenever we are getting more than 5000 uri form stage database from collector this status is always Cancelled instead of finished even though no error occurred while doing harmonization.

Marklogic version:9.0.5
DHF version:3.0.0+

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and it seems due to the Timeout we set on the MarkLogic Server. Did you tried increasing the timeout and then running the flow again?

Comment: This issue is not with timeout if document 5001,  job status will be always cancelled even though job was successful where as if count is 4999 job status is finished.I have fixed this issue by checking other parameter and updated one rest api to update job status once harmonization process is successful.

Comment: @vikas would you mind elaborating how you solved this problem? Is it a MarkLogic config issue or something specific to your flow?

Comment: we just  executed one url which executed one xquery against job database and updated and if in job there is no error for this job id ,i just updated status as "finished"